Use of tense in a completed project description
I am preparing a project portfolio for a job application in which I describe some of my completed projects in my current role. While the software is still in use today, the projects themselves are completed and I don't work on it anymore. The project description contains of a description of the software itself, technologies used, and some project circumstances that are somewhat relevant to something mentioned in the job description.
I am currently using mixed tenses in my descriptions, but I am unsure whether that's correct. An example:

I developed a X service for enterprise customers with feature A and B. Component C is based on state-of-the-art D and enables feature A. [...] The cross-functional project team consisted of multiple colleagues from the F department and the G Lab.

The development of the service as well as the project team are clearly things of the past, so I use past tense. However, the service still exists, so I am using present tense. However, I imagine this could be a bit strange when reading?
What's the correct use of tenses in this specific situation?

The verb constructions are fine, in particular logical. But the change of focus from product description to team description would be better if a new paragraph (ie for 'The cross-functional project team ...') were used.

You could use past tense in "Component C was based on state-of-the-art D..." if you prefer, but either is fine. (There are a lot of existing questions on mixing tenses, both here and on English Language Learners, but it's hard to find an exact match.)

The general point is that a description of the product uses the present tense, because it's still true now. But your actions were in the past, so they use the past tense.

All resumes leave out the I word: "Developed a X service..." You are reporting on that pro who did that amazing stuff, not yourself. Once you're working for the new folks, all that is behind you. All in the past, doesn't matter that it's still in use. This is spin, not mathematical logic.

Note, both English Language and Usage and English Language Learners are about language. Style and content advice when writing a CV are more on-topic at "The Workplace" Stack Exchange.
Language learners sometimes shy away from mixing tenses in close context, but there's nothing wrong with it if it makes sense.

Herman Melville wrote Moby-Dick in 1851 and, for some reason, people are still reading it today. I read it in high school and hope I will never have to again. I have heard of people liking it, but remember thinking at the time that they must have been faking it.

I would advise that you stay consistent from one entry of your CV to another, though. Don't follow "Google: I invented the search algorithm..." with "Microsoft: Design 'Clippy.'"

Thanks for your answer. In fact, my question was only about the correct use of tenses in above example, so this is primarily a language-related question.
